# Generating multiplication questions in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

The code should output a table for Farenheit and Celsius

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit\tCelsius");
    System.out.println("=======================");
     for(int temp = -45; temp <= 120; temp += 5) //for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i+= 10)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d       |",          temp);
            double sum = (temp + (9.0/5.0)) * 32;   
            System.out.printf("%5d", (int)sum );
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Are you getting  this error `java: variable answer is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[]) `?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Duplicate local variable answer @ samarth thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: By the way your code is not working as expected even after resolving the duplicate variable issue.

Comment: As @Samarth pointed the error is because you are initiating  int answer twice once  `int answer = input.nextInt();` and once `int answer = input.nextInt()`. Also you are comparing `question == yes` this means you are effectively checking if `question==nul`l you should be using a `do while` loop with condition `question=="yes"` instead of the if statement.

Comment: @JUAN's answer is working as expected look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `do while()` loop to continue with the questions, for example:

```
static Scanner input;
static Scanner scanner;
static String question;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + "? ");
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        while ((number1 * number2) != answer) {
            System.out.print("Incorrect. Please try again. What is "
                    + number1 + " * " + number2 + "? ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }
        if ((number1 * number2) == answer) {
            System.out.println("Correct. Nice work!");
            System.out.println("Want more questions yes or no? ");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            question = scanner.next();
        }
    } while (question.toLowerCase().equals("yes") ||
            question.toLowerCase().equals("y"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be do while loop.  Example:

```
do{
    // What you want to repeat and make sure to change have way to get out of loop like this:
    System.out.print("Want more questions yes or no? ");
    question = scanner.next();
}while(question.equals("yes") || question.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors in your code but instead of giving you the entire solution to your homework problem I suggest you start with the simple case of reading input until the user enters 'n':

```
    String input = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in); 

    while (!input.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("continue y/n?");
        input = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Add the generation of random ints, checking of answers etc inside the while loop body. Make sure to use equals instead of == when comparing two Strings